# Lifting of curves in characteristic zero

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, geometric-invariant-theory

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero. Let $G$ be an affine reductive group over $K$, and let $H$ be a closed reductive subgroup of $G$.
Since $H$ is reductive the GIT quotient $G/H$ exists.
Let $$f:\mathbb{A}^1\to G/H$$ be a morphism of varieties.

**Question**: Does $f$ admit a lifting to a morphism $\tilde{f}:\mathbb{A}^1\to G$ such that $\pi\tilde{f}=f$ where $\pi:G\to G/H$ is the canonical projection?

Comment: I believe this follows from "Strong Approximation" for homogeneous varieties.  I need to think about the details . . .

Comment: Looking at the fiber product $\mathbb{A}^1\times_{G/H}G$, an equivalent question is whether $H^1(\mathbb{A}^1,H)$ is trivial for $H$ reductive over $K$ (and the $H^1$ is étale or fppf).

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly: I think this follows from a theorem of Harder. For a semisimple group this is true for any affine curve but since any line bundle is trivial on $\mathbb{A}^1$, in this case it also holds reductive groups.